# Scaling input data in matlab neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, scaling

Is there any way to disable / change scaling method of input data in matlab neural network?
When I create network with newff I have to give min and max values of inputs...

I need it for testing because I wrote my own neural network and I am using scaling with mean and stddev - for testing I set mean = 0 and stddev = 1 so there is no scaling - I want to disable scaling onmatlab too...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of MATLAB do you have, but I suppose that it's a recent one, given that older versions didn't scale automatically inputs. I've just discovered this 'feature' recently and the way to disable it is quite simple: inside the neural network structure you can find a cell structure called 'inputs' which has inside another struct called 'processFcns', here you can remove the functions you don't need, such as 'mapminmax' (the scaling function) remembering to remove also the parameters saved into 'processSettings'. Don't forget to do the same for 'outputs' structure.

Comment: It says >> net.inputs{1}.processFcns
??? Error using ==> network.subsref
Error using ==> eval
Reference to non-existent field 'processFcns'.